# Right alignment of text in table cell

Tags: aspose, aspose.words

I populate word table like this (code below). And I would like to insert text in variable run aligned to the right. I have tried many things but nothing works. Can you please help?

```
var entryTable = bm.getBookmarkStart().getAncestor(com.aspose.words.NodeType.TABLE);
if (entryTable != null) {
    var myArray = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];
    var passes = myArray.length;
    var index = 1;
    while (...(id, myArray[0]+index)!="")
    {      
        var cRow = entryTable.getLastRow().deepClone(true);
        for (var j = 0; j < passes; j++) {       
            var run = cRow.getCells().get(j).getFirstParagraph().getRuns().get(0).deepClone(true);
            var key = ...(id, myArray[j]+index);
            run.setText(key);
            cRow.getCells().get(j).removeAllChildren();
            cRow.getCells().get(j).ensureMinimum();
            cRow.getCells().get(j).getParagraphs().get(0).appendChild(run);
        }
        index++;
        entryTable.appendChild(cRow);     
    }
    entryTable.getRows().get(1).remove();
} else {
    log.warn(LOG_PREFIX + "...");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to right-align all Paragraphs in a Table Cell.

```
Document doc = new Document("D:\\temp\\table.docx");

Table table = doc.getFirstSection().getBody().getTables().get(0);

for (Paragraph para : (Iterable<Paragraph>) table.getLastRow().getLastCell().getParagraphs())
{
    para.getParagraphFormat().setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.RIGHT);
}

doc.save("D:\\Temp\\18.11.docx");
```

Hope, this helps. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.